# How do I get Search data with express mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, rest

**This is my CRUD Code, Now I want to Perform a Search with dynamic values.**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const cors = require('cors')

//Importing Jobs Model
const JobsModel = require('../../models/jobs')


//POST Req 
router.post('/', async (req,res) => {
    const newJobPost = new JobsModel(req.body)
    try{
        const jobPost = await newJobPost.save()
        if(!jobPost) throw Error('Error, JobPost Not Saved...!')

        res.status(200).json(jobPost)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({msg:err})
    }
})

//GET All Req 
router.get('/',cors(), async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const getJobs = await JobsModel.find()
        if(!getJobs) throw Error('Error, No Jobs Found...!')
        res.status(200).json(getJobs)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({msg:err})
    }
})

//GET Single Req 
router.get('/:id',cors(), async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const getJob = await JobsModel.findById(req.params.id)
        if(!getJob) throw Error('Error, Job Not Found...!')
        res.status(200).json(getJob)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({msg:err})
    }
})


//DELETE Req 
router.delete('/:id',cors(), async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const delJobs = await JobsModel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
        if(!delJobs) throw Error('No Jobs Found to Delete...!')
        res.status(200).json({success: true})
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({msg:err})
    }
})


//UPDATE Req 
router.patch('/:id',cors(), async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const updateJob = await JobsModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)
        if(!updateJob) throw Error('Error, No Jobs Found to Update...!')
        res.status(200).json({success: true})
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({msg:err})
    }
})

//SEARCH Req


module.exports = router
```

Please anyone there help me to perform search query. I also did so much research on Google to find Solution for "Searching specific data from mongodb get req"......................................................................................

Comment: Kindly specify what you want to search for, required result and give a sample structure of your database or your Model

Comment: `const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const JobSchema = new Schema({
     title:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    company:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    city:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Jobs',JobSchema) ` This is Model File with all mongodb fields

Comment: What do you want to search for ? By title, or city or what ?

Comment: I want to Search by Title, Category and city

Comment: I am Really stuck in this please help @Qudusayo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finding elements in mongodb with mongoose usind **find()** function which takes in parameters that are optional.
To find by title, you need to find by anything which returns a callback function

```
JobsModel.find({title: req.body.title})
```

Comment: how do I perform find like this  ` //GET All Req 
router.get('/',cors(), async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const getJobs = await JobsModel.find()
        if(!getJobs) throw Error('Error, No Jobs Found...!')
        res.status(200).json(getJobs)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({msg:err})
    }
})`

Comment: As you seen my **Get, Post, delete and Update** how do i write **SEARCH** like that?

Comment: `//SEARCH Req
router.get('/:title',cors(), async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const findJobs = await JobsModel.find({title: req.body.title})
        if(!findJobs) throw Error('Error, Job Not Found...!')
        res.status(200).json(findJobs)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({msg:err})
    }
})` this is also not working

Comment: I use promise like:
JobsModel.find({ title: req.body.title }).then((results) => { / * Your Filter goes here* / }); The results in the then function is an array which you can now filter out result, Try Logging your results for quick solution.